# Agent to see real caller number with Twilio <Queue>

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I've built an IVR system and I cannot achieve how **agents can see real callers numbers**, not the proxy number (aka Twilio's number):

```
   $response->enqueue('commercial', ['waitUrl' => 'https://xxxxxxxion.com/playStory']);
            $call = $client->calls->create(
                '+407xxxxxxx15',
                '+403xxxxxxx56',
                array("url" => "https://xxxxxxxx.com/queues.php?type=commercial", 'timeout' => 15, 'record' => true, "statusCallback" => "https://xxxxxxxxx.com/notify.php", "callerId" => $_REQUEST['From'])
            );
```

I have tried an alternative with `"callerId" => $_REQUEST['From']` to get the Caller ID at the end of the call, but this parameter doesn't appear nowere.

With SIP calls is simple because I can set `From` parameter directly in the method call:

```
$call = $client->calls->create(
                'sip:xxxxxxx.sip.us1.twilio.com',
                $_REQUEST['From'], //here I set real Caller ID for Agent to see
```

Tried also with call forwarding, but cannot put the callers into a queue, or, at least to have a `waitUrl` for on-hold audio - the part I really need in this story.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

With Twilio you can only [set the `From` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#create-a-call-resource), the caller ID, of an outbound call, the call you are making using the REST API, to [a number you have either bought with Twilio or verified that you own](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/outgoing-caller-id).

The only way to forward on the original caller ID is to [use `<Dial>` to connect the calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial), but you say you need wait music.

One alternative you could use is to perform [a call whisper](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper) that reads out the number that the agent is about to be connected to, using [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say), and then connecting them to the queue.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I think it's not a real solution for my problem. It's possible to pass to `statusCallback` a param with the caller ID?

Comment: You can pass whatever parameters you like with your statusCallback URL by adding them as query parameters.

Comment: Oh, this can be an Idea. Thanks! 
Please update your response maybe in the future when  what I want will be available to use.